# Force jquery ui draggable to recalculate position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm building a highly dynamic page and need a way to force a draggable element to recalculate it's position.

Is there any way to call the same function that is being called when you're dragging the element (I assume it is mousemove event)? I need to call it from another function on another element scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

`Draggable` has some public methods to do what you want. Check out the [API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/) for more information, but I think that the specific method is `drag( event, ui )`. You can use it like this:

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({
  drag: function( event, ui ) {
    // Current CSS position of the helper as { top, left } object.
    var position = ui.position;

    // Current offset position of the helper as { top, left } object.
    var offset = ui.offset;
  }
});
```